# scss box shadow light up effect

Tags: css, sass

I'm not that good with all the properties of box shadow so I'd like to know how to do this bottom light effect for a navbar

[image: bottom light effect]

So far mines looks like this
[image: my navbar]

my current scss code:

```scss
.navbar {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b7bdbd;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: #262727;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #262727 0%, #505050 50%, #262727 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    left,
    #262727 0%,
    #505050 50%,
    #262727 100%
  );
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #262727 0%, #505050 50%, #262727 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px rgb(169, 169, 169);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can layer multiple box-shaddows with each one being softer than the previous one to create a more natural fade to the glow.

If only two values are given, they are interpreted as offset-x and offset-y values.

If a third value is given, it is interpreted as a blur-radius.

If a fourth value is given, it is interpreted as a spread-radius.

You also need to lower the opacity of the color to help it blend into the background.

```css
.navbar {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: #262727;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #262727 0%, #505050 50%, #262727 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    left,
    #262727 0%,
    #505050 50%,
    #262727 100%
  );
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #262727 0%, #505050 50%, #262727 100%); 
  box-shadow: 
  0px 4px 2px -2px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.4), 
  0px 10px 5px -5px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.3), 
  0px 20px 10px -10px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.2), 
  0px 40px 20px -20px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.1);
}

body {
  background: #262727;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">Text</div>
```